# multiple Insert query for existing row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which have 10 columns. I have to insert data for that table. I have some insert statements. first insert statement insert data for first 3 rows from one source. Now I want to insert data for next columns in same row using another insert statements from different source. These insert queries runs daily for table Order_Warehouse_Status, so we will have 1 row for daily transaction.

Ex. Table Order_Warehouse_Status have 10 columns like

```
Printed_PPS_Shipment,
Printed_Shipment_Lines,
Printed_Unit, 
Picking_Scheduled_Orders, 
Picking_Scheduled_Lines, 
Picking_Scheduled_Units, 
Pick_Complete_Orders, 
Pick_Complete_Lines, 
Pick_Complete_Units
```

Below 1st query insert data in first 3 columns. 2nd query should insert data for next column in same row. How to achieve this?

--1st Query

```
insert into Order_Warehouse_Status
(date , Printed_PPS_Shipment,
 Printed_Shipment_Lines,
 Printed_Unit) 
SELECT Getdate(), count(v_c_ship_ship_id) as Printed_PPS_Shipment, 
       count(ship_l_id) as Printed_Shipment_Lines, 
       count(allocated_qty) as Printed_Unit \
FROM [STG_WMS_Status_PPS_Line_QTY] 
where CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
      and shipment_status=2
```

--2nd query

```
insert into Order_Warehouse_Status 
(Date, Picking_Scheduled_Orders, 
 Picking_Scheduled_Lines, 
 Picking_Scheduled_Units) 
SELECT Getdate(), count(v_c_ship_ship_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Orders, 
       count(ship_l_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Lines, 
       count(allocated_qty) as Picking_Scheduled_Units 
FROM STG_Closed_Received 
where CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
      and shipment_status=7
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you want to change existing rows you should use UPDATE query instead of INSERT.

Comment: 2nd time You Can't Insert data You have To Update the Column Of That row ..In your Scenario I couldn't see any  common Column Which you can in use in join and update it..!!

Comment: is it happening same time..? for the second one you should use update..Also which column is the primary key here?

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for reply.
       I have date column in all the tables which have present date. I have updated the query. Now how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi first query will be same as insert and the second query you can do an Update statement with a where condition by checking whether the date is today's date...

```
  Update Order_Warehouse_Status 
  set Picking_scheduled_orders = i.Picking_Scheduled_Orders,
      Picking_Scheduled_Lines =  i.Picking_Scheduled_Lines,
       Picking_Scheduled_Units = i.Picking_Scheduled_Units 
       From(SELECT  count(v_c_ship_ship_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Orders, 
       count(ship_l_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Lines, 
       count(allocated_qty) as Picking_Scheduled_Units 
FROM STG_Closed_Received 
where CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
      and shipment_status=7)i
Where CONVERT (Date,'date column of Order_Warehouse_Status)
          = CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
```

No need to update 'date' column because it is already inserted in first query.Hope this will work if the inner select statement will return only one row..just check

Comment: Hi Sachu,  Thanks for reply

                  here 2nd query also having select statement which have filter like CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
      and shipment_status=7. then how we will check condition for today's date? Can you combined the query and guide me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sachu,
                 Thanku very much....Its worked perfect....Thanks for your quick responce.....

Comment: @ramu glad to hear it helped..mark it as answer and it will be helpeful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Both your first and second queries return just one row - some summary for the current date.

It would be somewhat logical to calculate this summary in a single query and `INSERT` the complete result as one row instead of inserting partial result at first and then looking for the row that was inserted to update the found row with the second part of the result.

```
WITH
CTE_Printed
AS
(
    SELECT
        count(v_c_ship_ship_id) as Printed_PPS_Shipment,
        count(ship_l_id) as Printed_Shipment_Lines,
        count(allocated_qty) as Printed_Unit
    FROM [STG_WMS_Status_PPS_Line_QTY]
    WHERE
        CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date) = CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
        AND shipment_status = 2
)
,CTE_Picking_Scheduled
AS
(
    SELECT
        count(v_c_ship_ship_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Orders,
        count(ship_l_id) as Picking_Scheduled_Lines,
        count(allocated_qty) as Picking_Scheduled_Units
    FROM [STG_Closed_Received]
    WHERE
        CONVERT(DATE,Inserted_date) = CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
        AND shipment_status = 7
)
INSERT INTO Order_Warehouse_Status
    ([Date],
    Printed_PPS_Shipment,
    Printed_Shipment_Lines,
    Printed_Unit,
    Picking_Scheduled_Orders,
    Picking_Scheduled_Lines,
    Picking_Scheduled_Units)
SELECT
    GETDATE() AS [Date],
    Printed_PPS_Shipment,
    Printed_Shipment_Lines,
    Printed_Unit,
    Picking_Scheduled_Orders,
    Picking_Scheduled_Lines,
    Picking_Scheduled_Units
FROM
    CTE_Printed CROSS JOIN CTE_Picking_Scheduled
;
```

Note, that I'm joining results of two queries using `CROSS JOIN` here without any condition. It will work efficiently and correctly in this case, because each of the two queries return exactly one row.

If you come across a situation, where you end up with several rows, then you'd need to determine a method of joining two result using some condition.

Comment: Hi Vladimir,    
                 It has worked for me....thanks for your valuable time.... :-)